# python icalendar rrule and daylight saving issue

Tags: python, icalendar, rrule

The following code fails at 23:53pm (04:53 UTC) on 11/7 (daylight saving Sunday) with the following ical:

```
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART;TZID=America/New_York:20211019T000000
DTEND;TZID=America/New_York:20211019T235959
RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=SU,MO,TU,WE,TH,FR,SA
X-STATE:con
END:VEVENT
```

The code works for for the day before and after and any other hour, but not for any time between local (NY timezone) from 23:00 to midnight.

```
from dateutil import rrule
from dateutil.tz import gettz
from icalendar.cal import Calendar
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone

cal_str = "BEGIN:VEVENT\nDTSTART;TZID=America/New_York:20211019T000000\nDTEND;TZID=America/New_York:20211019T235959\nRRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=SU,MO,TU,WE,TH,FR,SA\nX-STATE:convenience\nEND:VEVENT"

def test_ical(target_time):
    ical = Calendar.from_ical(cal_str)
    start_time_dt = ical.get("DTSTART").dt
    tzinfo = gettz(str(start_time_dt.tzinfo))
    start_time_dt = start_time_dt.replace(tzinfo=None).replace(tzinfo=tzinfo)
    end_time_dt = ical["DTEND"].dt if ical.get("DTEND") else None

    irrule = ical.get("RRULE")
    recurring_rule = irrule.to_ical().decode('utf-8')
    rules = rrule.rruleset()
    first_rule = rrule.rrulestr(recurring_rule, dtstart=start_time_dt)
    rules.rrule(first_rule)
    event_delta = end_time_dt - start_time_dt if end_time_dt else timedelta(days=1)

    return 1 if rules.between(target_time - event_delta, target_time + timedelta(minutes=1)) else 0

res = {}
for i in range(3,6):
    res[i] = {}
    for j in range(6,9):
        res[i][j] = test_ical(datetime(2022, 11, j, i, 53, tzinfo=timezone.utc))

print(res)
```

the output of the above code is:

```
{
 3: {6: 1, 7: 1, 8: 1}, 
 4: {6: 1, 7: 0, 8: 1}, 
 5: {6: 1, 7: 1, 8: 1}
}
```

My questions are: 1) Why? 2) what would be a workaround ical to make it work?